# HOW TO INSTALL openCV in Win7 -64-bit

Tags: windows, opencv, 64-bit, cmake

I am facing problem in installing openCV in Win7 -64bit, and i need to know how to do it?

i have downloaded http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/
131mb file from here and it doesnt contain any exe file, it contains some cmake file.

Help me.
Thanks,
sumit

Comment: Did that work for you? If so tell me what you did. I have the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, after extracting the files to a location like `c:\OpenCV-2.3.1\` you should setup a new project and link OpenCV libraries.

A couple of months ago I wrote a detailed tutorial explaining how to setup projects using Visual Studio 2010 in a 64bit machine. You can find the tutorial [here](http://www.anlak.com/using-opencv-2-3-1-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that you are not having trouble with your entire windows breaking down/slowing down. Please read this http://answers.opencv.org/question/3996/cannot-do-anything-with-opencv-anymore-on-windows/

If you are NOT having the same problem, I would love to hear how you managed to setup OpenCV to work with Visual Studio 2010 (or Visual C++ 2010 Express) on Windows 7 64-bit machine.

Once again, sorry that I technically unable to post it as a comment because I know that it is not ACTUALLY an answer.

Comment: I havent had any problems using OpenCV on my 64-bit Win7 machine using Visual Studio 2012. I've written a [blog post](http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/) which can help you with the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are your situation about, I can download a .exe from that page directly. The whole 131mb file is an exe file.

You may try [this direct link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack.exe/download).

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [blog post](http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/) which can help you with the installation. It includes detailed steps, right from adding the dll's to the PATH variable, to running a simple program. Hope it helps!